# Hierarchical Select and Panels modules: Any conflict?

Tags: panels, taxonomy-terms

I developed a content type having a field using "Hierarchical Select" module widget. I then developed its page using "Panels". Now "Hierarchical Select" loads the first dropdown list e.g. "Car Make" but not loading the subsequent dropbox of "Car Models". Any bug, or conflict between "Hierarchical Select" and "Panels" module??? Or I need to do any extra configuration. Plz help...

Comment: I'm using Hierarchical Select and Panels together successfully in Drupal 7, so there is no inherent conflict with the modules.  However, HS for D7 is a buggy mess and is basically unmaintained at the moment, as a quick search of the issue queue will show.  So you are likely to have a lot of problems, unfortunately...

Comment: You meant to say, you used HS and panels together in Drupal 6? Can you suggest any replacement of HS in D7?